# Integral of a triangle function in python

Tags: python, geometry, integral

I have just defined a function which is the integral of a given step function, and now I would like to integrate the triangle function obtained.[image]
jerk:1,-1,1-1
The step function correspond of a given list of successive jerk. For getting the triangle function,

I have used the formula: `a(t)=kt+ac` with k the Jerk and ac a constant which ensures the continuity and change for each step. But know, if I use the formula `v(t)=(1/2)kt^2+ac*t+vc`, I get negative value for velocity which is incorrect.

I have found some scipy function which return a number for an integral but I need a curve, do you have any idea of how I could integrate this? tks you

Comment: here you go, add the image of the curve

Comment: So you *have* the integral (as a number), but want it as a curve? Surely `vc` can be anything you like and you'll still have `v'(t)=a(t)`...

Comment: "I get negative value for velocity which is incorrect": why ?

Comment: When I use the formula, and you agree that v<0 is a nonsense ?! but well, it is a bit tricky to explain how I did it, and I think I would better use squad, tks anyway

Answer (score 1):

You can use `scipy.integrate.quad` function...

```
from scipy.integrate import quad

def g(x): # your triangle function
    return abs((x+1)%2-1)

for x in (0.1*i for i in xrange(40)):
    I = quad(g, 0, x)[0]
    print "x = %f -> g(x) = %f -> I(g, 0, x) = %f" % (x, g(x), I)
```

Is it the thing you are looking for?

@edit:

When the g function is discrete then you can sum the integrates of non-discrete intervals:

```
from math import floor
from scipy.integrate import quad

I = 0.0
for x in (1.0*i for i in xrange(4)):
    print "x = %f -> g(x) = %f -> I(g, 0, x) = %f" % (x, g(x), I)
    if floor(x) % 2 == 0:
        g = lambda x: 1
    else:
        g = lambda x: -1
    I += quad(g, x, x+1.0)[0]
```

Comment: Well, more or less because my triangle function is a discrete signal which depends of a step function, so it is not like y=f(x), do you see what I mean?

Comment: I've edited my answer, but I'm not sure if I figured out what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

This may be what your are looking for :

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import integrate

# step Function
def jerkstep(xprime,k):
    return (1 - 2*( int(xprime)%2 == 1 ) )*k

# Triangle function ( step integration)
def jerkint(x,k,ac): 
    return  integrate.quad( jerkstep ,0, x, args =(k) )[0] + ac*x

# Integrate of triangle
def jerkintint(x,k,ac,vc):
    return integrate.quad( jerkint, 0 , x , args = (1,0) )[0] + vc*x

# linearly spaced time samples (~ x axis)
t = np.linspace(2.0, 10.0, num = 100)

#optional arguments
k = 1
ac = 0
vc = 0

#output functions
jerk = np.array(t);
triangle = np.array(t);
curve = np.array(t);

# Warning : it can be long ( integration not optimized )
for indice,time in zip(range(len(t)),t): # Double indexation on t indices and t values
    print "Time, in seconds : ", time

    jerk[indice] = jerkstep(time,k)
    print "Step function : " , jerk[indice]

    triangle[indice] =jerkint(time,k,ac)
    print "Step function integrate ( = triangle ) : " , triangle[indice]

    curve[indice] = jerkintint(time,k,ac,vc)
    print "Step function double integrate ( = triangle integrate ) : " , curve[indice]
    print "\n"


# plot figure in mathplotlib
fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, 1, sharex=True, sharey=False)
axs[0].plot(t, jerk, 'o-', label=str("Step Function"))
axs[1].plot(t, triangle, 'o-' , label=str("Triangle Function"))
axs[2].plot(t, curve, 'o-' , label=str("Curve Function"))
fig.show()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Well I am a bit lost and I do not understand your code tbh, I am new in python.

Comment: how "new" are you  ? Do you at least know to install and use numpy/scipy ?

Comment: I started 2 weeks ago, yeah I installed it of course, otherwise I would have never get the previous curves. I need to try to understand your code.

Comment: I have detailed a bit more my program and if you run it (provided that you have the right libs) you should get the same output.

Comment: yeah it looks like what I want except that my step function change, it doesn´t have a constant max value, but tks for your code, I'll try to adapt it.